Docker image is not updating on Azure container registry via gitlab
I am having an issue with my docker images which are uploaded on the Azure container registry via gitlab, but they seem not to be updating the current code, but locally they work.
What could be a problem to my .gitlab-ci.yml file ?
image:
  name: docker/compose:1.25.4
  entrypoint: [""]

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

stages:
  - develop

build-dev:
  stage: develop
  before_script:
    - export IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
    - apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache bash
    - chmod +x ./setup_env.sh
    - bash ./setup_env.sh
    - docker login $AZ_REGISTRY_IMAGE -u $AZ_USERNAME_REGISTRY -p $AZ_PASSWORD_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $AZ_REGISTRY_IMAGE/proj:tag || true
    - docker-compose build --no-cache
    - docker tag $AZ_REGISTRY_IMAGE/proj:tag $AZ_REGISTRY_IMAGE/pixsar:$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
    - docker push $AZ_REGISTRY_IMAGE/proj:$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
    - docker system prune -af
  only:
    - develop
    - fix-docker-1

Additonal files :
Dockerfile
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.10

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the project code into the container
COPY . /app/

# Expose port 8000 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8001

# Command to run the startup script
CMD ["./startup.sh"]

# Command to run the application
CMD ["daphne", "app.asgi:application", "--port", "8001", "--bind", "0.0.0.0"]

and docker-compose  file :
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    env_file:
      - .env


This worked for me.


Note :- If you are using docker-compose version 1 you will receive warning but not error and it will also not build a new updated imaged.
Make sure in gitlab pipeline you are not getting error
For reference check this document.


I pulled a nginx image and pushed to azure container registry
.gitlab-ci.yml:
docker-build:
 # Use the official docker image.
 image:  docker:cli
 stage:  build
 services:
 -  docker:dind

 script:
 -  docker  pull  nginx
 -  docker  login  vshandilyaacr.azurecr.io  -u  vshandilyaacr  -p  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 -  docker  tag  nginx  vshandilyaacr.azurecr.io/azuregitlab:docker
 -  docker  push  vshandilyaacr.azurecr.io/azuregitlab:docker

 rules:
 -  if:  $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
 exists:
 -  Dockerfile

OUTPUT:



Thanks for the answer, but how will the web app automatically pick these new tags ? any idea

I have also added docker files maybe you can have a look

@LutaayaHuzaifahIdris If your tags names are always different after update then there are two ways to update the latest updated tag to web app you can add addition commands to update the tags in you web app or you can change it manually in web app->deployment center

If your image name and tags name remain same then there is no need to make changes in your web app. after some time web apps will automatically update to new image. but it takes some time

@LutaayaHuzaifahIdris if you are using single image then there is no need of docker-compose. Dockerfile is sufficient .

Ok makes sense, let me try and see

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
